# OKTA /authn/credentials/change_password API is throwing invalid provided error

Tags: okta

In OKTA Admin screen, I expired the password associated with my username.

Tried the primary authentication (/authn) as described in http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn.html.  Got the proper status back as PASSWORD_EXPIRED and also a state token.

Invoked the change password API (ie /authn/credentials/change_password) with the above state token and old/new passwords. Instead of getting the success message, I am getting the error message "E0000011: Invalid token provided".

My developer API token and state tokens are correct. Not sure why I am getting this error. Can you please help?

Thanks

Nara

Comment: Fixed this problem. Actually, my OKTA developer API token has expired. After creating a new token, the change_password API worked! Old token was working for some APIs and not for others which created the confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After you expire the password in the the UI, the user of the expired password is no longer in an ACTIVE state. Specifically, they're set to a PASSWORD_EXPIRED state which does not allow password resets. This is a security feature as the intent of explicitly setting a user in the state is to limit constrain their access to the system.

Note that the user event model is documented in the Okta Developer Guide at http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#user-status

Before you can change a user password, you need to re-activate the user.

```
curl -X POST    \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"     \
    -H "Accept: application/json"   \
    -H "Authorization: SSWS {{apikey}}"     \
    -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"    \
    -d '' https://{{url}}/api/v1/users/00u36pr8k9DMRAQBVMWZ/lifecycle/activate?sendEmail=false
```